# Dispaly three items of QStringList in one QtableWidget element

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qstring, qstringlist

I have a binary vector (it is in hex)

**For Example -**

```
x={0x06, 0xfc, 0x47}
```

I want to save it in a `QStringList` and then read it from the list and display all of them in one element of `QTableWidget`. How can I do this? I did this previously with a for loop but it only displays the last vector element `(0x47)` in the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 QStringList list;
 for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
 {
     list.append(QString::number(vector[i], 16));
 }
 // i - row, j - column in function join put your separator(for example "\n" if you want all items in new row)
 ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j, new QTableWidgetItem(list.join("\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have other items in the list, too, can I only join the first three items? @amiranys

Comment: Yes, you can like this
    `for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`

Comment: I mean I have a vector with 5 elements and I have append them in the QStringList. In other words I have 5 items in the QStringList and I only want to display the first three as a unit string. What about this? I mean I want to only join the first three items and display the other two items separately. @amiranys

Comment: @zahra, you can copy 3 items in new QStringList